# Is it on-topic to ask for a game which is set in a real world location?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-recommendations

On the one hand, it is not opinion based. On the other, there is no single definitive answer.

I don't care about the kind of game, but would like to explore some places where I have lived, for nostalgic reasons. The reality of the representation of the game is what is important to me - to walk those streets again, not some generic mock-up.

(Singapore, Hong Kong, Key West, if it matters ;-)

Comment: Have you tried Google Earth?

Comment: Google street maps might be better. I don't want to look down; I want to walk through streets (and into buildings)

Comment: You can tilt the view in Google Earth, and I think a lot of real-world buildings are modeled in it.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked at it in 10 years or more

Answer (score 5):

This would be a recommendation question, which is off-topic here.